# Android App Not Working on a different laptop

Tags: java, php, android, sql, eclipse

I am developing an android app. It works fine on my laptop, but if I use the same source code on a different laptop or android device it doesn't load certain things (such as lists which are linked to a remote SQL database). It loads fine on my laptop using the exactly SAME code and software versions.

What could be the possible reasons for this?

This is the error I am getting now:

```
03-21 23:42:20.174: W/dalvikvm(1037): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40014760)
03-21 23:42:20.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1037): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-21 23:42:20.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1037): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-21 23:42:20.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1037):     at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAtLocation(PopupWindow.java:791)
03-21 23:42:20.183: E/AndroidRuntime(1037):     at com.fokrul.justdeals.ActivityTab$2.onItemLongClick(ActivityTab.java:298)
```

and my line 298 is as follows:

```
   lvBooks.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener(){
                public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, final int position, long arg3) {
                    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)ActivityTab.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                    View viewInflated = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popupfile, null, false);
                    popup = new PopupWindow(viewInflated, Resizable.getDrawableWidth(getResources(), R.drawable.popup_menu), Resizable.getDrawableHeight(getResources(), R.drawable.popup_menu), true);

                    popup.setAnimationStyle(R.style.animation_popup);

                    View lvBooks = null;
    <THIS IS LINE 298>>>>> popup.showAtLocation(lvBooks, Gravity.NO_GRAVITY, view.getWidth()/2-Resizable.getDrawableWidth(getResources(), R.drawable.popup_menu)/2, view.getTop()+view.getHeight()/2);

                    setPopupListeners(viewInflated, position, bid);

                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Comment: Check your logcat -- most likely, you don't have access to the remote database.

Comment: I presume you're using Eclipse for development. Have a look in the LogCat - it sounds like something is wrong with the connection from your other laptop to the SQL database, so most probably you'll see an exception thrown in the LogCat.

Comment: There is no error thrown in logcat and connection parameters are all fine. How come same connection parameters and code works PERFECTLY fine on my laptop? ~It is accessing the same db on different laptop. And my remote db is accessed via PHP API's which are accessed by android device. Can it be an error with PHP???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing a `null` parameter in the `showAtLocation()` method. If you look at the [documentation for `showAtLocation(View, int, int, int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html#showAtLocation%28android.view.View,%20int,%20int,%20int%29), it says that it calls `getWindowToken()` on the `View`. Since it's `null` in your case, you'll get the `NullPointerException`. You'll need to make sure `lvBooks` is set to an actual `View`.